# Orfeo Toolbox (OTB) Haralick texture extraction not running

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 (Wien) 64-bit

When I run it this error immediately shows up:

Algorithm Haralick Texture Extraction starting...
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' See log for more details

I think my orfeo toolbox error because same problem when I run another tools(pansharpening), anyone can help me?

Comment: ok i will try 32-bit but, my friend install QGIS 2.6 64-bit and have OTB on QGIS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if Orfeo Toolbox is indeed installed. Although the toolbox is visible from within QGIS 64 bit it might still be that the toolbox has not been installed. It could also be that the path to the install has not been properly registered.

The 64 bit version of this version of QGIS does not include the OTB binaries. Install the 32 bit version of QGIS for OTB out of the box support.

Comment: How to check OTB is indeed installed and install path?
i only install QGIS 2.8.1 setup

Comment: It's better install QGIS 2.8.1 (Wien) 32-Bit. 64-Bit version not include Orfeo in default folder: http://bit.ly/1H7Phba

Comment: ok i will try 32-bit but, my friend install QGIS 2.6 64-bit and have OTB on QGIS??